# Browsers can read my feed but Feedburner says it can't locate it?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feedburner

I have a Wordpress-powered blog on my site and the default feed URL is http://www.peppyburro.com/blog/feed/. When I open this link in Firefox, it neatly displays the feed without a fuss. On Chrome, it does not format it but does recognize it nonetheless and displays the raw XML. Similarly, on Safari it prompts me if I want to add the feed to my reading list which means no issues locating the feed here either. However, when I use the same link on Feedburner, or a couple of other online readers, it says it couldn't locate the feed! What sorcery is this?

Answer (score 0):

Something on your end - one only has to fake the user-agent 
as Feedburner (not even the full 'FeedBurner/1.0 (http://www.FeedBurner.com)' ) 
, and your server fails to respond, but only sometimes.